# Converting integral equations to differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to convert integrals to differential equations, of any order. An example of an integral equation is given below, in Mathematica code. Could you please advise as to the command to use, and the format?

```
 q0[x]/20 == 10 (Integrate[{f0[t]/200 - f1[t]/200 + 0.5 (f40[t]/100)}, {x, 0, t}])
```

Comment: you have to be more specific: what kind of integral equations?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if this still isn't clear enough. Thanks

Comment: The thing inside your integral does not depend on `x`.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm trying to solve simultaneous differential equations, and one of them is shown above. However, Im trying to convert the integrals into differential equations to input them into NDSolve.

Comment: So, I was wondering if there is a way to input these equations into Mathematica itself to convert them. Thanks

Comment: If you switch the `x` and `t` in `{x, 0, t}`, then it's as simple as `diffeqn = D[integraleqn, x]`.  Is that really going to help you in your actual use-cases?

Comment: Thank you! I will try this, and comment once again with the results. Quick question, when you say "integraleqn", would I write "integraleqn1" etc. since I named the 29 equations eq1, eq2 etc.? In regards to the actual use, I am not sure if this will fix the issue, but I am going to try. If even after this, I still get a syntax error, I will probably look for more help, or post another question here! Thanks for your help @ Michael E2.